# D3.js text element is not displaying the value of function

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, display

I am trying to display certain values in my chart, although rather than the actual value being displayed, the function is. How can I display the actual return value of the function? The temperature displays well.

Furthermore, the `\n` doesn't work either. Is there any way that could be done?

An image of the output:
[image]

```js
d3.select(this)
.select('text')
.text("Date: " + function(d){ return d.date;} +
      "\nTemperature: " + y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2) + 
      "\nEvent: " + function(d){ return d.event;});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed code:

```js
d3.select(this)
  .select('text')
  .text(d => `Date: ${d.date} \nTemperature: ${y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2)}\nEvent: ${d.event}`);
```

I suppose there should be `d.pos.y` instead of `pos.y`, but it's how original code is written